# how to incorporate a help.chm file into a python application?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using python2.7.12 and i would like to know how do I add a *.chm file into a python script so as to have it launch properly when pressing the `F12` button?
Here is what i have so far:

```
def hchma():
    webbrowser.open_new(r"file://C:\WINDOWS\ULIX TxT Editor\Resources\helpCenter\helpCentre11.chm")

def hchm(event):
    webbrowser.open_new(r"file://C:\WINDOWS\ULIX TxT Editor\Resources\helpCenter\helpCentre11.chm")
```

but when i run this code on any Windows OS other than Win10, it will open up a web_browser instead of the file itself. This code works great with Windows 10 though.
Here is my root binding tag

```
root.bind('<F12>', hchm)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subprocess instead so it opens up directly

```
subprocess.Popen('hh.exe "C:\WINDOWS\ULIX TxT Editor\Resources\helpCenter\helpCentre11.chm"')
```